# Cant find component after instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

The code below gives me an error because no Record is found in prefab, GetComponent returns null. But after this method runs the gameobject apears in the hierarchy anyway,and i can see it has a record script on it. Its attached to the root gameobject of the prefab. It has no children.

```
    // SETUP CLASS

       private void LoadTracksAndSpawnRecords()
        {
            var tracks = TrackAndRecordLoading.Load ( PathToAudio, SettingsFile, () => gameObject.AddComponent<Track> () );
            var records = TrackAndRecordLoading.GetRecordPrefabs ( tracks );
            trackManager = new TrackManager ( tracks );
        }

// LOADER CLASS

        public static List<GameObject> GetRecordPrefabs( List<Track> tracks )
        {
            var recordPrefabs = new List<GameObject> ();
            foreach ( var track in tracks )
            {

                // This returns the correct prefab
                var prefab = SpawnPrefab.Instance.Spawn ( Prefabs.DynamicRecord );

              // This is null. Even though the inspector shortly after this line shows
              // the GO in hierarchy and it has Record script
              var record = prefab.GetComponent<Record> ();

                record.track = track;
                recordPrefabs.Add ( prefab );
            }
            return recordPrefabs;
        }


// INSTANTIATE
      public GameObject Spawn( string PrefabName )
        {
            // This returns the correct prefab
            var prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject> ( Prefabs.PathToPrefabsFolder + PrefabName );

           // This returns an clone. When visible in inspectors it has the "(Clone)" added // to its name
           return GameObject.Instantiate ( prefab, new Vector3 ( 0, 0, 0 ), Quaternion.identity );
        }
```

Comment: is Record on the prefab or is there another script that adds the Record compoenent?

Comment: Record is on the Prefab. So nothing needs to be done. Have I understood correctly that the moment Instantiate is called and executed it should all be available from the next line?

Comment: Well.. even using converttoentity for dots, I can spawn something and get the component on it next line, so, yes, you'd need to provide an [mcve] to recreate this as to why its not working

Comment: Ive updated the code in OP. Its literally all there is to instantiation. Its not a very big project either since its the start. Let me know if i should provide something better.

Comment: If you are instantiating an object with the `Record` MonoBehaviour on it, it should return as soon as you call `GetComponent`. The only reason this will return null, is if the object you instantiated does not have the script attached it it. This means one of two things: 1. This is a serious issue in Unity or 2. You missed something along the way. I'm going to bet it's #2; add debug lines everywhere and ensure you are instantiating and getting the correct prefab. Also ensure that the `Record` behaviour is setup directly on the prefab and not added in script

Comment: @Ron Will do. Although im already sure. I know the script is save inside the prefab. I have no instantiation code in the prefab. Just the attached Record. And i have stepped through line by line. But i will make further tests and get back. Im 99% sure this will end with me feeling humiliated. :D

Comment: @Daarwin nothing to be humiliated about; happens to the best of us. I once spent two days on a bug that for the life of me I didn't understand how to reproduce, only to realize I accidentally made a certain variable static :P

Comment: @Ron Hahah. I know the feeling. Thanks. I solved it now. Somehow i had made two classes called Record.

Comment: lol, glad you solved the mystery

Answer (score 0):

I had two classes called Record and that was the problem. The insantiation process is correct.